# Prove $F(x)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{-y^2+\sin(x+y)}dy$ is differentiable .

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $F: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be define via

$$F(x):=\int_{\Bbb{R}} e^{-y^2+\sin(x+y)} dy.$$

Prove $F$ is differnentiable at all $x$ and that

$$F'(x)=\int_{\Bbb{R}} e^{-y^2+\sin(x+y)}\cos(x+y)dy.$$

So my gut intuition is that this is either an application of the MCT or DCT. I wanna say its MCT if I can set

$$f_n:=e^{-y^2+\frac{n}{n+1}}$$

But my issue is with the $h$ in the denominator of showing the following exists:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{\Bbb{R}} \frac{e^{-y^2+\sin(x+h+y)}-e^{-y^2+\sin(x+y)}}{h}dy.$$\

So I get stuck with the $h$ being in the denominator so to remedy this, I figured setting my $f_n$ to

$$f_n:=\frac{e^{-y^2+\frac{n}{n+1}}}{h}$$

But am unsure if this works. Any hints or tips greatly appreciated. Oh and if I was to use DCT, my $g$ would be $e^{-y^1+1}$ and perhaps over $h$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you could go for $n/(n+1)$. This question is essentially asking: can we differentiate under the integral sign?

That is, can we say: $$\lim_{h\to0}\int\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}\,\mathrm{d}y=\int\partial_1f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y$$Well, clearly if the difference quotients $(f(x+h,y)-f(x,y))/h$ can be dominated the DCT would apply. Observe that $e^{-y^2+\sin(x+y+h)}-e^{-y^2+\sin(x+y)}=e^{-y^2+\sin(x+y)}\cdot(e^{\sin(x+y+h)-\sin(x+y)}-1)$ is bounded in magnitude by $e^{1-y^2}\cdot\max(|e^h-1|,|e^{-h}-1|)=e^{1-y^2}\cdot(e^{|h|}-1)$ ($\sin$ is Lipschitz with constant $1$).

Now recall that $e^x=1+x+x\cdot\psi(x)$ where $\psi$ is a continuous function that tends to zero as $x\to0$. In particular, $e^{|h|}-1=|h|(1+\psi(|h|))$. For small enough $h$ we can bound $\psi(|h|)$ by $1$, say, and have $e^{|h|}-1<2|h|$. Then for these $h$ we find the difference quotients are bounded by $e^{-y^2}\cdot 2e\cdot|h|/|h|=2e\cdot e^{-y^2}$ which is integrable, so that the DCT applies.

Comment: so I was correct with using $g:=e^{-y^2+1}$? I just needed the max part?

Comment: @anonymous yes I guess so. But you didn't seem to try to bound the difference quotients themselves, only to try to bound $e^{-y^2+\sin(x+h)}$, which is important. I've also just realised I made a huge omission which I will now rectify (done)

Comment: But can the dominating function contain $h$?

Comment: @anonymous No, not in the usual DCT. In the GDCT ... *almost*, but not quite, there are some other conditions needed if the dominating function depends on $h$

Comment: would my $f_n:=e^{-y^2+\frac{n}{n+1}}$ which converge pointwise to $e^{-y^2+\sin(x+y)}$ and $\vert f_n \vert \leq 2e^{-y^2+1}:=g$

Comment: @anonymous your $f_n$ does not converge pointwise to the thing you claim. Take a moment to think about it.

Comment: how about $f_n:=\frac{e^{-y^2+\sin(x+y+\frac{1}{n})}-e^{-y^2+\sin(x+y)}}{\frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: @anonymous That is just the expression I used. I highly doubt this thing satisfies the conditions for monotone convergence; for dominated convergence you just use the same (or similar) analysis as mine.